# Modifying image map hover tooltip

Tags: tags, hover, tooltip, area

I have working example of image map (not taking credit for it).

http://jsfiddle.net/w713qevm/

```
$('.one,.two,.three').css({
    position: 'absolute'
}).hide()
$('area').each(function(i) {
    $('area').eq(i).bind('mouseover mousemove', function(e) {
        $('.one,.two,.three').eq(i).css({
            top: e.pageY+10,
            left: e.pageX+10
        }).show()
    })
    $('area').eq(i).bind('mouseout', function() {
        $('.one,.two,.three').hide()
    })
})
```

I'm trying to modify tooltips from following cursor to displaying in specific position. However when I modify this scipt position is always relative to page (like absolutely positioned). I want to make it relative to image and can't do it.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show what modifications you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code sample

```
function(e){...
   .css({
      top: e.pageY+10,
      left: e.pageX+10
    })
...
}
```

The e represents the event triggered by the mousemove and mouse over.  The CSS position is based on the event location.  Just change the CSS to be an absoloute position. See below.

```
function(e){...
   .css({
      top: 50,
      left: 50
    })
...
}
```